# Symfony2: background color of date widget

Tags: css, forms, symfony

For a template that includes a date field widget, non-date input fields will have their background colors changed per CSS.  The same does not occur on the date widget.  How should the background color of the date widget be effected? (Adding an attr array in the form class has no effect.)

A screenshot of the (small but real) difference: [image]

Code samples: 
Template:

```
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.fname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.sname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.dateAdded, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'} }) }}
```

Form class:

```
        ->add('fname', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('sname', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('dateAdded', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'choice',
            'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
            'pattern' => '{{ year }}-{{ month }}-{{ day }}',
            'years' => range(Date('Y'), Date('Y') - 5),
            'required' => false,
            'data' => date_create(),
        ))
```

CSS:

```
.smallform {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: #000066;
    border: 1px solid #CCCC99;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A less-than-subtle solution: modify the date widget in my application's customized copy of fields.html.twig.  The more precise solution would be to define a specific widget for this, or figure out how to retain the class attribute all the way into the date widget:

```
{% block date_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    {% else %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {{ date_pattern|replace({
                '{{ year }}': form_widget(form.year, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}),
                '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}),
                '{{ day }}': form_widget(form.day, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}),
            })|raw }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock date_widget %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    ->add('fname', null, array(
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'smallform')
    ))
    ->add('sname', null, array(
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'smallform')
    ))
    ->add('dateAdded', 'date', array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'smallform'), // ADDED
        'widget' => 'choice',
        'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
        'pattern' => '{{ year }}-{{ month }}-{{ day }}',
        'years' => range(Date('Y'), Date('Y') - 5),
        'required' => false,
        'data' => date_create(),
    ))
```

also, view-source to make sure the classes are actually set in the html tags, it could be a problem with your CSS.

There is a problem with these lines:
`<td>{{ form_widget(form.fname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>`
I dont think you can set a class on the entire widget, only for individual rows.
you can try this if you need to set the class via twig.

```
<form action="" method="">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.fname, { 'attr': {'class': 'smallform' } }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.sname, { 'attr': { 'class': 'smallform' } }) }}
    <div class="smallform">
        {{ form_row(form.dateAdded) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  As I noted above, adding the attr array (e.g. `'attr' => array('class' => 'smallform'))` in the form class does not help in the case of a date widget.  And applying the class to the text widget in the template does work.

Comment: ok I figured this out, because the date widget uses several div(s) it ignores the class property for some reason. you can wrap form_widget in a div and apply the class yourself maybe. added to original post.

Comment: I wish it was that simple.  Using the code I show above, here's the rendered HTML on my page: `<td><div id="clienttype_dateAdded"     class="smallform">...` - the class appears in the div tag but the background remains unchanged.

Comment: FWIW: this does not work either: `->add('body', 'select', array('attr' => array('class' => 'smallform')))`