# Symfony2 changing forms date input class in twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am confused on how can I overwrite the code of the forms template to match my needs.. For example when I create a date input fields it is very long and I want to change it with my class. I am reading this documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html however I have no clue on how to use the example for my needs: This is what I already did:

I added the horizontal theme in config.yml:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:
        resources: 
            - 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig'
```

This is how I make the data field input:

```
>add('DateOfBirth', 'date', array(
    'label' => 'Date Of Birth * ',
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Date of Birth')))
```

It renders this template:

```
<div id="form_DateOfBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth" class="form-inline">
    <select id="form_DateOfBirth_month" name="form[DateOfBirth][month]" class="form-control"></select>
```

I need to change my class in `selected` to this:

```
<div id="form_DateOfBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth" class="form-inline">
     <select id="form_DateOfBirth_month" name="form[DateOfBirth][month]" class="span1"></select>
```

How can I do this? From the documentation the only thing I know i need to do is this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block date_widget %}

{% endblock date_widget %}


 {{ form(form) }}
```

And then what? ;/

I am trying to do something like this:

```
{% block date_widget -%}
            {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' span1')|trim}) -%}

    {%- endblock date_widget %}
```

But i am getting undefined variable attr... ;/

**UPDATE**

The code: `{{ form_widget(form.DateOfBirth, {'attr': {'class': 'span1'}}) }}` is not what I need.

This changes the class of the whole div. I need to change the class of the field `select`, which has a class `form-control`

This is what I get (`class="span1 form-inline"`):

```
<div id="form_DateOfBirth" class="span1 form-inline"><select id="form_DateOfBirth_month" name="form[DateOfBirth][month]" class="form-control"></select></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the whole widget like that means that change would affect every other form. What if you need in some other template long input? You can simply add extra classes to your input individually. For instance something like this:

> That would be in your FormType class

```
->add('DateOfBirth', 'date', array(
    'label' => 'Date Of Birth * ',
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Date of Birth',
        'class' => 'your_custom_css_class' // Add more if needed
    ))
)
```

or

> That would be in your twig template for instance

```
{{ form_widget(form.birthdate, { 'attr': {'class': 'your_class'} }) }}
```

You can also apply customizations to a specific field of your form. More on that subject you can read [here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)

*- Update -*

Take a look at this [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919456/2763926)

Comment: @Dominykas55 added extra link with info.

Comment: This looks like it could work, however I am getting undefined variables on widget and date_pattern...

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
{{ form_widget(form.DateOfBirth, {'attr': {'class': 'span1'}}) }}
```

With form being the form view passed from the controller to the view

See doc : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html

EDIT :

> This changes the class of the whole div. I need to change the class of the field select, which has a class form-control

This is exactly how it works from my side, i'm using the same syntax (I'm working with both Symfony 2 and bootstrap) and it only changes the class for the input/select element and not the surrounding dir (I only use form_widget() method too)

Could you print us what you can see when you use this code please?

Comment: Hello :) Sure i can, I did, could you check mine too ?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can give class by separate to the date both year month and day for example if the date is by name DateOfBirth would look like this


{{form_widget(form.DateOfBirth.day , {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

{{ form_widget(form.DateOfBirth.month , {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

{{ form_widget(form.DateOfBirth.year , {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
```

Comment: Keep in mind:  A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.